# Show point or uniform convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Given is the sequence of functions $f_n(x)= \sqrt{\frac1{\sqrt n} + x^2}$ with x element of the real numbers.

If I am correct, the following is the limit value $$f(x) = \lim f_n(x) = \lim \sqrt{\frac1{\sqrt n} + x^2} = |x|$$

Unfortunately, it is not clear to me how I can now show the  uniform convergence.

The beginn would be:
$$|f_n(x) -f(x)| = |\sqrt{\frac1{\sqrt n} + x^2} - |x||$$

How does the assessment go on?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your limit for the pointwise convergence is not correct: $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+x^2}=\sqrt{\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+x^2}=\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$$ since $y\mapsto\sqrt{y}$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$

So the function is continuous on $\mathbb R$ and thus the sequence has a candidate for a uniform limit.

**Hint:** Regarding the uniform convergence, we aim to show/or disprove that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=0$.
Observe the difference: $$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\left| \sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+x^2}-|x|\right|$$
on different intervals at first (they are intervals where it is differentiable...), what can you say?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.